# Export PATH variable on postfix pipe

Tags: postfix, environment-variables

I am using a custom transport to process incoming mail. It is used for subscribing and unsubscribing to a certain channel.

```
twailer   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=twailer argv=/home/twailer/twailer/bin/twailer
```

The twailer binary is a Javascript file and should be parsed with node, so I added the shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

But that does not work, because `$PATH` is not exported by the pipe command.
According to the manual, I can specify which environment variables to pass in a setting `export_environment` in `main.cf`, so I did that too.

```
export_environment = TZ MAIL_CONFIG LANG PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

But it still does not work. So I replaced my binary with a shell script that outputs the current `$PATH` to stderr and I get

```
Command output: /usr/bin:/bin
```

which is clearly not what I configured.

Any ideas on how I can get my $PATH variable passed?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to make pipe(8) do something it doesn't, consider adapting to what it does support:

```
twailer   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=twailer argv="/usr/bin/node /home/twailer/twailer/bin/twailer"
```

Replace "/usr/bin/node" with the real path to your binary.

As to your problems with hacking in a PATH: as documented,

> argv=command... (required)
>                 The command to be executed. This must be  specified
>                 as the last command attribute.  The command is exe-
>                 cuted  directly,  i.e.  **without  interpretation  of
>                 shell  meta  characters  by  a shell command inter-
>                 preter.**